# XSLT check and create child node with default values if souurce is missing

Tags: xslt, grouping, default-value

I need to validate the source XML and look for `Attributes/Attribute/Name`. If `Name = 'ComplexAttr'` then make it child node of `Data/Attributes(where @Type='common')/Collection/ComplexAttr`. And if it is not present then create a node with default values. However, I have to validate all nodes with `@Type='ComplexAttr'` so it should be as dynamic as possible.
In the source XML you can see that I have only 1 node where `@Type='ComplexAttr'`. However, in the Transformed sample XML I have two nodes for `<Attr>`. This is I want to do with the following XSLT. Please let me know how I can do this.
Thanks in advance.

XSLT:

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [<!ENTITY key "concat(Type[. != 'ComplexAttr'],substring('common',1 div (Type = 'ComplexAttr')))">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="type" match="Attribute" use="&key;"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data Schema="XML A">
            <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="XML/Attributes/Attribute[
                            generate-id() = generate-id(key('type', &key;)[1])
                         ]">
                <xsl:sort select="&key;" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <errorCodes>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="XML/Attributes/Attribute"
                                     mode="errors"/>
            </errorCodes>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute">
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent-Grouping-Key" select="&key;"/>
        <Attributes type="{$vCurrent-Grouping-Key}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('type',$vCurrent-Grouping-Key)"
                                 mode="out"/>
        </Attributes>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="out" name="makeAttr">
        <Attr id="{id}" name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr']" mode="out">
        <Collection id="" name="test">
            <ComplexAttr refId="0">
                <MaskValue />
                <xsl:call-template name="makeAttr"/>
            </ComplexAttr>
        </Collection>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="errors"/>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute[Value='']" mode="errors">
        <errorCode>"value for <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> is missing."</errorCode>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<XML>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute>
            <id>5</id>
            <Name>Buyer ID</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value>Lee</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>331</id>
            <Name>Enviornment</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value>Development</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>79</id>
            <Name>Retail</Name>
            <Type>common</Type>
            <Value></Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <id>402</id>
            <Name>Gender</Name>
            <Type>category</Type>
            <Value>Men</Value>
        </Attribute>
    <Attribute>
         <id>1197</id> 
         <Name>UPC</Name> 
         <Type>ComplexAttr</Type> 
         <Value>Testing</Value> 
         <Path /> 
    </Attribute>
</Attributes>
```

---- Transformed XML

```
<Data Schema="XML A">
    <Attributes type="common">
        <Attr id="5" name="Buyer ID" value="Lee" />
        <Attr id="331" name="Enviornment" value="Development" />
        <Attr id="79" name="Retail" value="" />
        <Collection id="" name="test">
            <ComplexAttr refId="0">
                <MaskValue />
                <Attr id="1197" name="UPC" value="Testing" />
                <Attr id="123" name="Size" value="Test" />
            </ComplexAttr>
        </Collection>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes type="category">
        <Attr id="402" name="Gender" value="Men" />
    </Attributes>
    <errorCodes>
        <errorCode>"value for Retail is missing."</errorCode>
    </errorCodes>
</Data>
```

Comment: @Iwburk thanks for formatting. Can you tell me what was not formatted so I will be careful next time.

Comment: Sure. The main thing is to indent every line of a large code block with 4 spaces. You can do this automatically by selecting the block and clicking the `{}` icon above the textarea. I also like to format any other code, even code that's in the middle of a sentence. You can do this using `{}`, as well, or, manually, by surrounding the code with backticks (the character above the `tab` key).

Comment: @Iwburk - thanks for the tips. I will follow your suggestions to make the code more readable and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Complete stylesheet with more push style approach (it's late, you know...)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="type" match="Attribute" use="Type"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Data Schema="XML A">
            <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="XML/Attributes/Attribute[
                            generate-id() = generate-id(key('type', Type)[1])
                         ]">
                <xsl:sort select="Type" order="descending"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
            <errorCodes>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="XML/Attributes/Attribute"
                                     mode="errors"/>
            </errorCodes>
        </Data>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute">
        <xsl:if test="Type!='ComplexAttr'">
            <Attributes type="{Type}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('type',Type)"
                                     mode="out"/>
                <xsl:if test="Type='common'">
                    <Collection id="" name="test">
                        <ComplexAttr refId="0">
                            <MaskValue />
                            <xsl:apply-templates 
                                 select="key('type','ComplexAttr')"
                                 mode="out"/>
                        </ComplexAttr>
                    </Collection>
                </xsl:if>
            </Attributes>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="out">
        <Attr id="{id}" name="{Name}" value="{Value}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr']" mode="out">
        <Attr id="{id}" 
              name="{Name}{substring('UPC',1 div not(Name[normalize-space()]))}" 
              value="{Value}{substring('Testing',1 div not(Value[normalize-space()]))}"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute" mode="errors"/>
    <xsl:template match="Attribute[Value='']" mode="errors">
        <errorCode>"value for <xsl:value-of select="Name"/> is missing."</errorCode>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Data Schema="XML A">
  <Attributes type="common">
    <Attr id="5" name="Buyer ID" value="Lee"/>
    <Attr id="331" name="Enviornment" value="Development"/>
    <Attr id="79" name="Retail" value=""/>
    <Collection id="" name="test">
      <ComplexAttr refId="0">
        <MaskValue/>
        <Attr id="1197" name="UPC" value="Testing"/>
      </ComplexAttr>
    </Collection>
  </Attributes>
  <Attributes type="category">
    <Attr id="402" name="Gender" value="Men"/>
  </Attributes>
  <errorCodes>
    <errorCode>
    "value for Retail is missing."
    </errorCode>
  </errorCodes>
</Data>
```

Comment: @Alejandro. Thanks for your response. You are correct that is what I need to do. However after making changes and added the code as you suggested I'm not getting the expected output. In the Collection element it is not giving me any Attr. However, it is repeating Collection element as many times as I have @Type='ComplexAttr'. Looks like it is calling <xsl:template match="Attribute[Type='ComplexAttr']" mode="out"> as many times it finds @Type='ComplexAttr'. I have changed the position() > 0. Now I'm getting all the Attr in Collection elements. However, it is still repeating Collection elements.

Comment: @Alejandro. It is not creating default Collection element if @Type=ComplexAttr is missing from source XML. How I can do this?

Comment: +1 @Alejandro. Excellent solution as always. Thanks for your help.